# VS Code Python: How to stop live reloading?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

It's super annoying and I can't figure out how to turn it off. It worked nicely until the last 2 updates of VS Code. Now it's a nightmare because every time when I change the code and it's still working it tries to reload live, then throws some exception. I can't get rid of it.

I tried to add "--no-reload" into launch.json but then VS Code refuses to launch the project because it shows error "unknown argument" or so.

I'm using Flask and the exception is always thrown in werkzeug:

[image]

My launch.json:

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "autoReload": {"enable": false},
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "application.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger"
            ],
            "jinja": true,
            "justMyCode": false
        }
```

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify which web framework you are using. Since you tagged this with Python, I'm guessing you are using [one of the supported app types](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_debugging-specific-app-types), and live reloading is a feature of the framework, not of VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [devblog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-may-2021-release/) from Microsoft announcing this change. But essentially you need to add/edit the following in *launch.json*:

```
"autoReload": {"enable": false}
```

Comment: I tried but no effect - it still throws the exception :(

Comment: @mimic, I had a typo in the answer, `false` should be lowercase, not capitalized as I had in the answer.

Comment: Yes, @pavel I noticed it else it wouldn't build :) (see my launch.json in the question after this update) but it's still not working :-(

Comment: Don't you have any other ideas how to fix it, @pavel ? It's so incredibly annoying to see this exception all the time :-((((

Comment: @mimic, sorry no other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but in case someone needs this, just add `"--noreload"` to the args list